# Call to a member function role() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, laravel, model, controller

I am using laravel and I am having trouble with the model/controllers.

class BaseController extends Controller

```
$id = Session::getId();
if (!empty($id)) {
  $user = User::find($id);
  $role = User::find($id)->role()->first();
```

This is the User Model

```
 class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    ........
/**
* An user can have only one role
*/
public function role() {
    return $this->hasOne('role_assignments', 'user_id');
    }
```

This is the Role_Assignments model

```
class Role_Assignments extends Eloquent {
public static $timestamps = true;

/**
* A role can have several users
**/
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}
}
```

Tables (sorry But I cannot post images and only 2 links).

All Tables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jf1U.jpg

Users:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p9ut.jpg

Roles:

i.imgur.com/hsWnSVJ.jpg

Role_assignements:

i.imgur.com/6H3KK7F.jpg

Edit:

I changed it to and it seems to get the ID

```
        if (Auth::check())
            {
                 $id = Auth::user()->getId();
            }

    if (!empty($id)) {

        $user = User::find($id);
                    //print_r($user);
        $role = User::find($id)->role()->first()->role_id;
                    $configtable = DB::table('config')->where('id', '1')->first();
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. can you add the complete error message? We don't see which line throw an error. I guess it's `User::find($id)->role()->first()`, so it seems that `User::find($id)` doesn't return the expected object.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the error is from User::find($id)->role()->first()

Comment: Does your `roles` table contains a `user_id` or `users` table contains a `role_id`?

Comment: No, but my role_assignments table has user_id and role_id

Comment: Post your database structures for both tables.

Comment: Ok, I've posted them (sorry, but I cannot post images and only 2 links).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `find` method by `findOrFail`, I'm pretty sure that `User::find($id)` return null in your case

Answer (score 0):

> Call to a member function role() on a non-object

According to the `error` your following code is problematic:

```
$role = User::find($id)->role()->first();
```

In this case `User::find($id)` is not returning a `User` model/object so the calling of another method on a `non-object` is throwing the error. At first make sure why you are not getting a `user` object and then make sure your relationships are right, seems wrong to me because both `Model` has a similar type of relation `hasOne/hasmany` but one should be `belongsTo/belongsToMany` and finally the following code:

```
User::find($id)->role()->first();
```

Should be like this:

```
User::find($id)->role; // for hasOne
```